# HTML/ AJAX/ JQuery Drill-Down Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a html site for troubleshooting problems, in which the user selects an answer to a question and then another question is loaded based on the answer, and then another question based on that answer and so on until they drill down to a solution.

I've looked around on here for something similar but all I've found so far is quite simple code that hides all divs then changes the display options based on which radio button is selected - with the number of questions I want to load I dont think this would be suitable...

I think the best way to do it would be to find a way to store all of the different questions in a separate file then use an onclick event to load the correct one depending on which radio button is selected... preferably using AJAX. Problem is I'm extremely rusty with my js/ajax and have no idea where to begin with this!

I realise it sounds like I'm asking practically asking someone to write it for me haha! but even if someone knows of any tutorials or can just point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try [JQuery-Drilldown](https://github.com/Cinamonas/jquery-drilldown)

A Demo and Instructions are in the Link below. Just look at the tags and the JavaScript